# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли здесь выделять деепричастный оборот "применяя данные материалы" или он тесно связан со сказуемым?

Как видно из рис. 2, материалы этой серии обладают на порядок более высокой прочностью по сравнению с фторопластом, следовательно можно получить более высокие характеристики ЗРА (,) применяя данные материалы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая нужна, т.к. оборот не связан со сказуемым.

Comment: > Запятая нужна, т.к. оборот не связан со **сказуемом**. - со **сказуемым**

Answer (score 1):

Как видно из рис. 2, материалы этой серии обладают на порядок более высокой прочностью по сравнению с фторопластом, следовательно**,** можно получить более высокие характеристики ЗРА**,** применяя данные материалы.

Где ж он связан? Оборот можно убрать из предложения без потери смысла.

**Она идет по жизни смеясь.** Вот где тесная связь со сказуемым! Попробуйте убрать деепричастие.

Еще одна запятая пропущена — после "следовательно".